# Jruby line-numbering problem?

Tags: ruby, jruby

Given the following snippet:

```
hash = {                  # 1
  (line = __LINE__) =>    # 2
    lambda { x }          # 3
}
```

Doing some inspection on jruby:

```
puts line # >> 2
puts hash[line].inspect >> #<Proc:0x560932fe@/tmp/test.rb:2>
```

Seems to differ from the standard mri:

```
puts line # >> 2
puts hash[line].inspect >> #<Proc:0x00007fa59733d760@/tmp/test.rb:3>
```

The proc appears to be on line **3** in mri, whereas in jruby, it is line **2** ... is this a bug ? Any workaround for this ?

Comment: Most likely a bug. JRuby does have a few of these here and there where frames aren't aligned quite the same. Most of the time they're small enough not to notice. If you can, help come up with some test cases where they're wrong (there should be a few, try some with block dispatch as well) and post them to http://bugs.jruby.org/.

Comment: @jtbandes: The reason why it bothers me is that i'm implementing serializable_proc (http://github.com/ngty/serializable_proc) using ruby_parser, which does static code analysis, and i need the line number generated by Proc#inspect to identify which line i want to the processing, since jruby gives me inaccurate line-numbering, SerializableProc doesn't work as expected. Anyway, SerializableProc may not have practical use, but i guess it will just be one of my fun projects to see how far i can push the idea of serializing a proc.

Comment: @nick: Yup, just reported the bug @ http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-5014 (with the spec file illustrating the discrepancies).

Answer (score 0):

if it differs from MRI it's probably considered a bug